# Terraform arguments must be maps or objects, got "string"

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp

#### Expected Behaviour

I'm trying to iterate through var.vm_settings but doesn't seem to cooperate.
The error doesn't make sense because the required type for the input variable is "string"

#### Actual Behaviour

throws error (see Error output)

#### Error Output

```
Error: Error in function call

  on ..\main.tf line 4, in locals:
   4:   vm_settings = zipmap(keys(var.vm_settings), [for vm_setting in values(var.vm_settings) : merge(var.vm_defaults, vm_setting)])
    |----------------
    | var.vm_defaults is object with 12 attributes

Call to function "merge" failed: arguments must be maps or objects, got
"string".
```

#### Terraform (and AzureRM Provider) Version

#### Affected Resource(s)

- `azurerm_v2.25.0`
- `terraform v0.13.0`

#### Terraform Configuration Files

**Main.tf**

```
locals {
  vm_settings = zipmap(keys(var.vm_settings), [for vm_setting in values(var.vm_settings) : merge(var.vm_defaults, vm_setting)])
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "oracle_db" {
  for_each = local.vm_settings

  name                            = each.key
  resource_group_name             = var.resource_group_name
  location                        = var.location
  size                            = each.value.size
  admin_username                  = each.value.admin_username
  admin_password                  = local.admin_password
  disable_password_authentication = each.value.disable_password_authentication
  priority                        = each.value.priority
  eviction_policy                 = each.value.eviction_policy
  zone                            = each.value.zone
  network_interface_ids           = [azurerm_network_interface.nic.id, ]

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = each.value.admin_ssh_key.username
    public_key = each.value.admin_ssh_key.public_key
  }

  identity {
    type = each.value.identity.type
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = each.value.os_disk.caching
    storage_account_type = each.value.os_disk.storage_account_type
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = each.value.source_image_reference.publisher
    offer     = each.value.source_image_reference.offer
    sku       = each.value.source_image_reference.sku
    version   = each.value.source_image_reference.version
  }

  boot_diagnostics {
    storage_account_uri = each.value.boot_diagnostics.storage_account_uri
  }
}
```

**Variables.tf**

```
variable "vm_settings" {
  description = "Map of vm's to create (keys are vm names). Allowed values are the same as for vm_defaults."
  type        = any
  default     = {}
}

variable "vm_defaults" {
  type = object({
    name                            = string
    size                            = string
    admin_username                  = string
    admin_password                  = string
    disable_password_authentication = string
    priority                        = string
    eviction_policy                 = string
    identity = object({
      type = string
    })
    admin_ssh_key = object({
      username   = string
      public_key = string
    })
    os_disk = object({
      name                 = string
      caching              = string
      storage_account_type = string
    })
    source_image_reference = object({
      publisher = string
      offer     = string
      sku       = string
      version   = string
    })
    boot_diagnostics = object({
      storage_account_uri = string
    })
  })
  default = {
    name                            = null
    size                            = null
    admin_username                  = null
    admin_password                  = ""
    disable_password_authentication = null
    priority                        = null
    eviction_policy                 = null
    identity = {
      type = null
    }
    admin_ssh_key = {
      username   = ""
      public_key = null
    }
    os_disk = {
      name                 = null
      caching              = null
      storage_account_type = null
    }
    # Image used to create the virtual machines.
    source_image_reference = {
      publisher = ""
      offer     = ""
      sku       = ""
      version   = ""
    }
    boot_diagnostics = {
      storage_account_uri = ""
    }
  }
  description = <<EOT
virtual machine default settings (only applied to virtual machine settings managed within this module)
    vm_settings = {
    size                            = (Required) The SKU which should be used for this Virtual Machine, such as Standard_F2.
    admin_username                  = (Required) The username of the local administrator used for the Virtual Machine. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.ring
    admin_password                  = (Optional) The Password which should be used for the local-administrator on this Virtual Machine. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
    disable_password_authentication = (Optional) Should Password Authentication be disabled on this Virtual Machine? Defaults to true. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

    # Spot VM to save money
    priority        = (Optional) Specifies the priority of this Virtual Machine. Possible values are Regular and Spot. Defaults to Regular. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
    eviction_policy = (Optional) Specifies what should happen when the Virtual Machine is evicted for price reasons when using a Spot instance. At this time the only supported value is Deallocate. Changing this forces a new resource to be created. This can only be configured when priority is set to Spot.

    # type of Managed Identity which should be assigned to the Linux Virtual Machine
    identity = {
      type = (Required) The type of Managed Identity which should be assigned to the Linux Virtual Machine. Possible values are SystemAssigned, UserAssigned and SystemAssigned, UserAssigned.
    }

    # SSH key
    admin_ssh_key = {
      username   = (Required) The Public Key which should be used for authentication, which needs to be at least 2048-bit and in ssh-rsa format. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
      public_key = (Required) The Username for which this Public SSH Key should be configured. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
    }

    # Internal OS disk
    os_disk = {
      name                 = (Required) The Type of Caching which should be used for the Internal OS Disk. Possible values are None, ReadOnly and ReadWrite.
      caching              = (Required) The Type of Caching which should be used for the Internal OS Disk. Possible values are None, ReadOnly and ReadWrite.
      storage_account_type = (Required) The Type of Storage Account which should back this the Internal OS Disk. Possible values are Standard_LRS, StandardSSD_LRS and Premium_LRS. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
    }

    # Image used to create the virtual machines.
    source_image_reference = {
      publisher = (Optional) Specifies the publisher of the image used to create the virtual machines.
      offer     = (Optional) Specifies the offer of the image used to create the virtual machines.
      sku       = (Optional) Specifies the SKU of the image used to create the virtual machines.
      version   = (Optional) Specifies the version of the image used to create the virtual machines.
    }

    boot_diagnostics = {
      storage_account_uri = (Optional) The Primary/Secondary Endpoint for the Azure Storage Account which should be used to store Boot Diagnostics, including Console Output and Screenshots from the Hypervisor. Passing a null value will utilize a Managed Storage Account to store Boot Diagnostics.
    }
  }
EOT
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually if you have a default map and you want to combine it with user provided map, the following is enough:

```
merge(var.vm_defaults, var.vm_settings)
```

The above will use values from `var.vm_settings`, and everything else will be from `var.vm_defaults`.

So your `local.vm_settings` would be:

```
locals {
  vm_settings = merge(var.vm_defaults, var.vm_settings)
}
```